# Как расширишь footer с помощью css (height-свойство)?

Tags: html, css, html5, frontend

Footer хочу расширить именно с помощью свойства height. Не получается.

left menu и content сделаны left и right FLOAT, соответственно.

По какой причине футер не виден и не расширяется?

```css
 .container {
                    position: relative;
                    height: 2000px;
                    margin: 0px auto;
                    min-height: 100%;
                }
               
                .header {
                   width: 100%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: palegreen;
                   height: 150px;
                }
               
                .left-menu {
                   width: 30%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: aqua;
                   float: left;
                   height: 300px;
                }
               
                .content {
                   width: 70%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: teal;
                   float: right;
                   height: 300px;
                }
               
                .footer {
                   width: 100%;
                   height: 150px;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: palegreen;
                }
```

```html
<body>
       
<div class="container">

<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="left-menu">MENU</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Чем обусловлено использование float ?  Почему не flex ?

Comment: float - классика вёрстки. должен работать при умелом использовании.

Comment: Таблицы тоже классика, это не значит что их надо использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
 .container {
                    position: relative;
                    
                    margin: 0px auto;
                    
                }
               
                .header {
                   width: 100%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: palegreen;
                   height: 150px;
                }
               
                .left-menu {
                   width: 30%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: aqua;
                   float: left;
                   height: 300px;
                }
               
                .content {
                   width: 70%;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: teal;
                   float: right;
                   height: 300px;
                }
               
                .footer {
                   width: 100%;
                   height: 150px;
                   border: 4px;
                   background: palegreen;
clear: both;
                }
```

```html
<body>
       
<div class="container">

<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="left-menu">MENU</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: clear: both - как объяснить механику действия?

Comment: @Dmitry Nikitin отменяет обтекание у блока с  определенных сторон - http://htmlbook.ru/css/clear

Comment: как же (куда?) обтекание проходило, что футер  ( до clear: both ) исчезал полностью?